# StandardOpenOption issue java

Tags: java

I have this simple java code:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Write {
   public static final String PATH = "/home/user/Desktop/hello.txt";

   public static void main(String[] argv) {
      Path path = Paths.get(PATH);
      OutputStream out;
      try {
         out = Files.newOutputStream(path, CREATE, APPEND); 
      } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("Caught IOException: "+e.getMessage());
      }

   }
}
```

which wont compile due to this error:

```
Write.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        out = Files.newOutputStream(path, CREATE, APPEND); 
                                          ^
symbol:   variable CREATE
location: class Write
Write.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
     out = Files.newOutputStream(path, CREATE, APPEND); 
                                               ^
symbol:   variable APPEND
location: class Write
2 errors
```

Usually this means that I've forgotten to import some stuff.
I even tried to add:

```
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption
```

But I get the same error.

**EDIT:** Ok so, I've solved my problem by following @rmlan advice. I did miss those constants. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your import from:

```
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption
```

to

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*
```

In order to reference the enum constants from the StandardOpenOption class as you have (without any qualification):

```
Files.newOutputStream(path, CREATE, APPEND);
```

You must import all enum constants from that class statically (or at least statically import the specific ones that you are using).

**Alternatively**, as other answers have mentioned, you can keep the import you added, but in that case you *must* fully-qualify the references to the enum constants of StandardOpenOption:

```
Files.newOutputStream(path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll either have to make your import static

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
```

or use the static reference from StandardOpenOptions

```
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

Files.newOutputStream(path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

These are static members, you have to either prepend the class they're in

```
StandardOpenOption.APPEND
```

or do a static import

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.APPEND;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.CREATE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.APPEND;
```

or

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*
```

instead of `import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption`